# Test Action Sampler in JMeter 5.0

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a requirement in JMeter (version 5.0), I have multiple thread groups in my Test Plan. 2nd **Thread Group** should start execution only after few seconds of, 1st **Thread Group** get started. And same like remaining thread groups.

Here I couldn't see `Test Action Sampler` plugin in JMeter version 5.0.

Does any other suggestions / way to achieve this task ?

Answer (score 4):

`Test Action` Sampler was renamed to [Flow Control Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) (with more features)

For delaying a [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group) you can also use `Startup Delay`:

> Thread Group also provides a scheduler. Click the checkbox at the bottom of the Thread Group panel to enable/disable extra fields in which you can enter the duration of test, the startup delay, the start and end times of the run. You can configure Duration (seconds) and Startup Delay (seconds) to control the duration of each thread group and the after how much seconds it starts. When the test is started, JMeter will wait Startup Delay (seconds) before starting the Threads of the Thread Group and run for the configured Duration (seconds) time.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Since [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) it's called [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action)

[image]

Going forward pay attention to [JMeter Changelog](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) and the [history of previous changes](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

It has been renamed to Flow Control Action as per release notes:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: you're welcome. To say thanks in Stackoverflow , you upvote , and if (first)answer is ok (which is the case), you accept answer by click on the check sign on the left of question.